# Help with maximum area problem

Tags: calculus

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

Consider the parabolic arch whose shape may be represented by the graph of $ y=144-x^2 $, where the base of the arch lies on the​ x-axis from $ x=-12 $ to $ x=12 $. Find the dimensions of the rectangular window of maximum area that can be constructed inside the arch.

I'm pretty much at a loss as to how to approach this problem. If someone could please work it out step by step and show me how to solve the problem, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a point $p$ at the considered arc, that is, $p=(x,144-x^2)$ for some $-12\leq x\leq 12$. Drawing a picture, we see that the maximum area of the windows which have $p$ as a vertex is $$(12-x)(144-x^2).$$
If we pick a window with the maximum area, it must have some point of the arc as a vertex, otherwise we could just expand one of its sides a little bit and enlarge its area.

So, the maximum area of the windows in the arc is the maximum of the function $f(x)=(12-x)(144-x^2)$. We first need to find its local maximum and minimum points. Deriving it and equaling to $0$, we get
$$ f'(x)=3x^2-24x-144=0\ \Rightarrow\ x=-4 \mbox{ or } x=12.$$
So the maximum area is the maximum of the values of $f(-12)$, $f(-4)$ and $f(12)$. Since $f(-12)=f(12)=0$, it follows that the maximum area is $f(-4)=2048$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[image]

Loock at the figure: we have $B=(x,144-x^2)$ and the area of the rectangle is:$$
S_{ABCD}=2x(144-x^2)
$$

can you maximize this function?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw a picture. Exploit symmetry and only maximize on the positive side of the y axis. What is the area of this half of the rectangle? Its width is $x$ for some $x<12$ and its height, in order to be inscribed in the parabola, must be $144-x^2$.

This gives you a univariate function to maximize in the usual way.